# Existing umlauts don't get displayed in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code, encoding

- I want to open a .csv-file with umlauts (ÄÖÜäöüß).
- However, instead of those letters this symbol: � is displayed.
- Using notepad with utf-8 encoding, the file is rendered correctly. So the file can't be the source of the problem.
- In vsc, utf-8 is also selected. I reopend it with different encodings but none work.
- Adding umlauts works just fine. I can write an ä in the opened file and it gets displayed as it should.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you looked with an hex editor/dump what the content of the file is, how are these umlaut characters encoded

Comment: what is the value for setting **File: Encoding** `files.encoding`

Comment: @rioV8 I am not sure what I have to look for, but in hex the "Ü" is encoded as "DC", which seems to be the according hex-number for this letter.

Comment: @rioV8 Files:Encoding is set to UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

Enabling "Files: Auto Guess Encoding" in vsc makes it work.

Opening the file with notepad and saving it with "utf-8 with bom" (encoding can be chosen in the "save as"-window makes it work in vsc.

Comment: VSC does not need a BOM